# Android - set birthday to an existent contact

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am trying to set a birthday to the android contacts provider to an existent contact which doesn't have the field, I have tried to use the method I use to update the birthday of a contact which **already** has a birthday set:

```
fun updateBirthdate(id: Long, birthdate: String) {

    val list = ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>()

    val where = """${ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID}  = ?
        AND ${ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE} = ?"""
    val whereParams =
            arrayOf(id.toString(), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)

    list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(where, whereParams)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, birthdate)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY)
            .build())

    context.contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, list)
}
```

But it's not working, I also tried to insert a new row:

```
list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, birthdate)
            .withValue(CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY)
            .build())
```

But none of the above works, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, your method `updateBirthdate` has a bug, if you have a contact that has multiple events set for it, e.g birthday, anniversary, etc. your code will override all of them.

you should instead query to find the specific **raw** contact in which that event is saved, and update only that specific raw contact (add Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID = ? to your selection).

when updating an existing contact that doesn't currently have a birthday you're right to change the `update` to an `insert` however the `withValueBackReference` line will only work if you're currently creating a new raw contact, which I assume you do not.
so change that to a regular `withValue` and add to ID of the raw contact you're trying to add the birthday to